# Excel sum range & next set of range numbers

Tags: excel, sum, formula

Trying to do something which I think is quite easy but I cant figure it out.

I have a row of about 1000 items. I want to sum for items (A1:H1) and then (I1:Q1) and so on until I get to the end. When I try to do (A1:H1) and drag the formula button across it then gives me (B1:I1). Im trying to avoid this.

Thanks!

Comment: By "formula button" do you mean "fill handle"?

Comment: Yes - thats what i was referring to

Comment: Where are you trying to display these sums? If this is something like a running sub-totals, like A1:J1 in J2, K1:T1 in T2, this is simple. If you want them side-by-side in a table, it is not so simple.

Comment: Side by side in another sheet

Comment: Not sure I understand. A1:H1 comprises 8 columns, yet I1:Q1 comprises 9. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly convoluted but the below should work for you. You will need to add in the names of your sheet instead of "Sheet1", it essentially works off of the column reference of the cell the formula is placed into, I had it starting in column A.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!"&ADDRESS(1,(((COLUMN()-1)*8)+1))&":"&ADDRESS(1,(COLUMN()*8),1,1)))
```